# Select * from and AES_DECRYPT one column from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, aes

I have a database where only one field is AES_ENCRYPTed, I am trying to figure out how to decrypt just that one field in the query...

My code:

```
$getGVI = mysqli_query($com, "SELECT *,AES_DECRYPT(os_location, 'My AES Key') FROM vehicles WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Exactly **HOW** is this not working for you? as written, there's nothing wrong with the php or sql so we can't do anything to help you, since you haven't told us exactly what's wrong.

Comment: My bad, it doesn't actually decrypt the os_location column, when I echo it in my PHP, it's still encrypted

Comment: @tadman, thanks for the comic, I don't use user data input in this sql query, it's all called from other SQL queries that I designated as PHP variables.

Comment: @tadman, at that, add the strings are also addslashed

Comment: `addslashes` should **never** be used for this sort of thing, that is not a SQL escaping function. Just use placeholders and `bind_param`. You're creating massive amounts of risk here. Any time you're adding dynamic data to a query, use placeholders unless you have a very, very good reason.